# what json format is solr expecting

Tags: json, solr

I'm new to solr and I'm trying to index the `books.json` file inside the exampledocs directory using `post.sh`:

But what I get is this:

[image]

Here's the `books.json` file:

```
[
  {
    "id" : "978-0641723445",
    "cat" : ["book","hardcover"],
    "name" : "The Lightning Thief",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 12.50,
    "pages_i" : 384
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1423103349",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "The Sea of Monsters",
    "author" : "Rick Riordan",
    "series_t" : "Percy Jackson and the Olympians",
    "sequence_i" : 2,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 6.49,
    "pages_i" : 304
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1857995879",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "Sophie's World : The Greek Philosophers",
    "author" : "Jostein Gaarder",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "fantasy",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 3.07,
    "pages_i" : 64
  }
,
  {
    "id" : "978-1933988177",
    "cat" : ["book","paperback"],
    "name" : "Lucene in Action, Second Edition",
    "author" : "Michael McCandless",
    "sequence_i" : 1,
    "genre_s" : "IT",
    "inStock" : true,
    "price" : 30.50,
    "pages_i" : 475
  }
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can only post xml using post.sh

XML should be of this format:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="employeeId">05991</field>
    <field name="office">Bridgewater</field>
    <field name="skills">Perl</field>
    <field name="skills">Java</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="employeeId">05992</field>
    <field name="office">Bridgewater</field>
    <field name="skills">Perl</field>
    <field name="skills">Java</field>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <field name="employeeId">05993</field>
    <field name="office">Bridgewater</field>
    <field name="skills">Perl</field>
    <field name="skills">Java</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

For more info:

post.sh: http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html

xml format: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages

---

If you want to post JSON, depending on version of Solr, you can configure JSON request handler in solrconfig.xml, and then post JSON as follows:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json?commit=true' --data-binary @books.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

Please refer to this documentation on how to post json: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post.jar to feed the json to Solr as well

```
java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/update/json -Dtype=application/json -jar post.jar *.json
```